# how can I use multiple Players in J2ME to simulate streaming over Http

Tags: java, http, video, java-me, streaming

I need to connect to a http server from a phone and play a movie while downloading. I understand that you can simulate this using multiple players (Manager.createPlayer(...)) in J2ME but I dont know how.

Thanks

Comment: anything 'advanced' in j2me will only work on 1 or 2 phones (if you are lucky). So unless this is for a project for yourself, don't bet on techniques like this for a mainstream app,

Answer (score 0):

I just want to suggest some possible approach. But, these methods also depends on device's implementation of MMAPI.

1. Use RTSP protocol instead of HTTP. It needs server side support
2. Create new DataSource class which downloads video data by using socket
3. Get video data by using socket and append it to file. While downloading it pass file data to MMAPI as file:/// protocol